# How do you view multiple tables at the same time in ArcMap 10?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, ux

My original question was:

> How do you undock the tables in the ArcMap attribute window?

because that's how I thought it should work in the new ArcGIS 10 docking environment.  Either it isn't intuitive or I am missing something obvious.

I have an ArcMap user who went up to ArcGIS 10 yesterday and he wants to view two tables at the same time. If he opens two tables, they are loaded as tabs in the table window.  He(we) try to drag one tab elsewhere and nothing happens.  The only window control button is an 'X' which closes the table.

If I right-click on the tab, **Close** is the only option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image: Viewing Multiple Tables]

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00qp00000015000000.htm

Check
Table window is set to vertical or horizontal by using the following **Arrange Tables** commands on the Table Options menu.

Comment: That's the way I thought it should work.  I'm not getting the dock guides, but the Table Options menu works perfectly!

Comment: After I used the **Arrange Tables** for the first time, the docking guides work correctly.

Comment: Glad it has helped, yes can be annoying when Arrange Tables are not active.

Comment: Yesterday, I was helping another user remotely and the docking guides don't display.  So the **Arrange Tables** from the Table Options menu saves the day again.