# Losing attribute table when working remotely

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table

Because of the pandemic my work is strictly remote. I remote into my work computer via laptop. I have two monitors connected to that laptop. Sometimes when I move the ArcMap desktop program from one screen to another my attribute table is lost beyond the visual monitors and it takes a while to get it back. Online I found that unplugging and plugging my desktop from my monitors is the only thing that works. However it is only a stroke of luck that I can click on the attribute table before it disappears again. Every time this happens I loose a good 20 minutes.

Does anyone have a better solution that doesn't involve randomness/luck or me going to the office to change my remote computer settings (we are not allowed in the office until May).

Comment: This seems less a GIS issue than a general IT one, and not something which is generally reproducible.

Comment: You can do it through registry key https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000007907#:~:text=If%20the%20attribute%20table%20is,it%20to%20the%20primary%20monitor.

Comment: you can use this method as well https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1983/how-do-you-view-multiple-tables-at-the-same-time-in-arcmap-10

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ArcMap Attribute Table not seen when second screen disconnected from Main Computer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277304/arcmap-attribute-table-not-seen-when-second-screen-disconnected-from-main-comput)